# How to fix Attribute model is not defined error

Tags: product-attribute, frontend, catalogsearch, magento2.4.5

When we search from the search box on the top of the header of the website at that time displayed error like

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The attribute model is not defined.

please if you have any idea then please share here.